# Why does RDD is persisted to disk using sparklyr's spark_read_csv?

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparklyr

I have a Spark cluster with two workers - all the nodes have 16GB of RAM.
I am reading the data from S3 to Spark using sparklyr spark_read_csv (code below) with MEMORY = TRUE parameter, but despite having enough memory most of the data is spilled to disk. RStudio server is installed on the same node as Spark master. Any ideas why is this happening and if this is optimal? How I could tune it? Thanks!

```
flightsFull <- spark_read_csv(sc, "flights_spark", 
                          path =  "/s3fs/mypath/multipleFiles", 
                          header = TRUE,
                          memory = TRUE,
                          columns = list(
                            Year = "character",
                            Month = "character",
                            DayofMonth = "character",
                            DayOfWeek = "character",
                            DepTime = "character",
                            CRSDepTime = "character",
                            ArrTime = "character",
                            CRSArrTime = "character",
                            UniqueCarrier = "character",
                            FlightNum = "character",
                            TailNum = "character",
                            ActualElapsedTime = "character",
                            CRSElapsedTime = "character",
                            AirTime = "character",
                            ArrDelay = "character",
                            DepDelay = "character",
                            Origin = "character",
                            Dest = "character",
                            Distance = "character",
                            TaxiIn = "character",
                            TaxiOut = "character",
                            Cancelled = "character",
                            CancellationCode = "character",
                            Diverted = "character",
                            CarrierDelay = "character",
                            WeatherDelay = "character",
                            NASDelay = "character",
                            SecurityDelay = "character",
                            LateAircraftDelay = "character"), 
                          infer_schema = FALSE)
```

[image]

**Edit:** adding config files content

**spark-defaults.conf**

```
spark.master=spark://ip-host.eu-west-1.compute.internal:7077
spark.jars=/opt/bluedata/bluedata-dtap.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath=/opt/bluedata/bluedata-dtap.jar
spark.driver.extraClassPath=/opt/bluedata/bluedata-dtap.jar
```

**spark-env.sh**

```
SPARK_MASTER_HOST=ip-host.eu-west-1.compute.internal
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=8
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=32768m
```

**Edit2** - added executors pane
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, can you add the spark configuration file ? spark-default.conf and spark-env.sh

Comment: Can you also attach Environment? How do you `spark-submit` the app?

Comment: `sparklyr` is just calling `CACHE TABLE` so it's likely an environment/defaults issue

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that you use the default memory options to `spark-submit` your Spark application and despite having enough memory to use you don't.

`384.1` is the default storage memory that you used up and hence Spark started persisting blocks to disk.

My understanding is that you have a Spark Standalone cluster with the standalone Master and **one** standalone Worker. That's what `spark-env.sh` suggests (no number of workers specified) and that's what I can see in the number of Spark executors in the screenshot as Spark Standalone gives as much Spark executors as there are standalone workers.

My *guess* is to increase the memory properties for the driver and executors and start over. That will increase the memory space and less disk use.

I've also noticed that the Storage Level for the RDD in question is **Disk Serialized 1x** so sparklyr could have decided to set the storage level itself (given memory constraints). It is usually to be specified by a Spark developer, but `spark_read_csv` may *somehow* decide on it itself.

Comment: It would be more useful if you actually checked the docs, but to make it easier there is  `CACHE TABLE` involved here (`spark_read_csv` -> [`spark_partition_register_df`](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/blob/9c830cecf3a91de0857dc33ef3b375c2f922ddd1/R/dplyr_spark_data.R#L18))  Don't ask me why `sparklyr` decided to use it :)

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. `spark_read_csv` indeed has a parameter called `options`, however doc does not tell which ones can be passed there. The connection itself can be also modified in the `spark_connect` config parameter. I will have a look at this and experiment.